# Use a Linux directory as a USB-OTG device to an Android phone?

Tags: usb, android, usb-otg

I have a really strange idea and I was wondering if I could do it.

Many Android custom recoveries allow placing backups in both the internal storage, the external (ie: microSD) storage, and additionally to a [USB-OTG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_On-The-Go) device.

While I don't own a OTG cable, is there a way that I could "fake" an OTG device to my Android phone using my Ubuntu Linux desktop? I'd like to be able to do backups right to my computer in this manner, rather than doing it to an external storage location, then copying it to my computer.

Can I fake a USB-OTG device to my Android device using a local directory in Linux?

Answer (score 1):

The IOIO board interfaces to Android as an OTG device. You can even use the power to the IOIO board to charge the android phone. More info here: https://github.com/ytai/ioio/wiki

You could use the board's UART port to create an interface to the pc. I am currently using this board to spit out data from my app to a microcontroller and it works very well.

You will probably need to write some software to make it work at both ends but the hard work seems to have been done.

Comment: Very interesting, but kind of outside of the scope of what I'm asking for. I may as well at this point just buy a USB-OTG adapter and call it a day. Still, very interesting, something to keep in mind.