# Configure Linux system as an OTG device

Tags: usb, embedded, usb-otg

I'm wondering if it's possible to make a Linux system appear like an USB peripheral.

Like smartphones which can switch from master to slave depending on the device they are connected to, I would like to know if it's possible to have the same behavior with a Linux system.

For example, I have an embedded Linux on a card with usb connectors, when I plug a usb key to this card, the usb key is detected as a slave device and mounted on the file system.
Now if I connect my card to my computer I would like to have it recognized as usb slave device too.

Do you think it's possible?

I found a similar question asked but not answered [Use a Linux directory as a USB-OTG device to an Android phone?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/132625/use-a-linux-directory-as-a-usb-otg-device-to-an-android-phone)

---

I finaly chose to try to configure the system as MTP device instead of presenting it as mass storage for those reasons :

- Protect against concurrent file access
- Protect system against crash or corruption due to concurrent file access or bad mounting/unmounting
- Possibility to expose root file system without unmounting or stopping it
- Possibility to share multiple devices

As I have some problems configuring it I oppened a new question [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/388304/no-udc-shows-up-for-usb-mass-storage-gadget-with-configfs) for those interested.

Comment: The USB hardware on the 'card' must support OTG as well. From personal experience the modules are available when compiling the kernel **IF** the hardware supports it.

Comment: Oh and on my embedded system the USB hardware DID support OTG, but it was not wired up on the the circuit board so I was unable to use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can, but it is not easy. You need at least a little work with it.

Working as an USB slave is supported in Linux since around the 2.4 or 2.6 times. You have to find a compatible chip, then a device having it, and then buying one, somewhere (typically, to rent it on the Internet).

Specifically for USB gadgets, there is support for peripherial devices and also for block devices.

Your Google search: Linux USB gadget . You may also have a little dig task in the kernel sources, this slave-side mode is likely not included in most distribution kernels, so you will have to recompile it.

[Here](http://www.linux-usb.org/gadget/) is an old, but still actual reference about this. Other may be useful [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/217967/52236).

---

<sub>Extension by @Arkaik:</sub>

A userspace MTP responder is available [uMTP-Responder](https://github.com/viveris/uMTP-Responder), it's easy to implement and relies on either gadgetfs or functionfs.

Comment: Thanks for the links, it makes it a lot clearer for me. The Mass Storage Gadget seems interesting but it need a separated file or partition when I need to access the root file system.
Maybe it's possible to makes the system act like an MTP device to the host?

Comment: @Arkaik You can give your root filesystem to it, although it is a little bit dirty. If you won't crash your root fs, I suggest to export it only readonly (for example, `losetup -r /dev/loop0 /dev/sda1`, and then exporting `/dev/loop0`). It will be buggy, but it will mainly work. For a filesystem-level sharing, [this](https://www.heise.de/download/product/google-gadgets-for-linux-54978) may be interesting (will work only with Android). Search for *wtp linux gadget* on the google.

Comment: @Arkaik There is even a [user space USB gadget api](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/gfx-docs/drm/driver-api/usb/gadget.html) in Linux.

Comment: Mount it as a read-only loop device could be nice but I will not be able to write files on the card.
I'll dig around this USB gadget API and come back ;)

Comment: @Arkaik Android can do this, so the gadget exists. I am not sure if it is in kernel space.

Comment: Hi, after some digging around, seems that the best solution will be to use MTP. I want to be sure I'll not crash rootfs or corrupt file on shared partitions.
Also it seems that few open-source MTP responders exists but not in the mainline kernel. Will have to port it to my system. Not sure I'll succeed as I'm already having troubles with installing gadgetfs module.... 
I'll come back to post a full answer if I suceed

Comment: @Arkaik Giving access to something to overwrite anything in your root filesystem, is dangerous. I think you are on a good way to make your phone to a brick. I am not sure, MTP responders should even exist in the kernel, it looks to me as a nice userspace thing.

Comment: I think the security will be implemented with access right on files and directories. But I have to expose the rootfs, even if the user is not able to write in. I precise that the application is not for a phone at all ^^.  Finally, I have no problem with userspace MTP responder but wherever the responder is placed, it'll need an access to hardware. So my problem now is to configure a mtp interface with configfs and functionfs to communicate with hardware from userspace. If you want take a look at my new question where I explain my problem with more details