# No UDC shows up for USB mass storage gadget with configfs

Tags: usb-drive, usb-device

I'm currently trying to make USB mass storage gadget work on a raspberry pi zero W.

My main objective is to implement both mass_storage and mtp responder functions into one gadget but it'll come later.

I followed this documentation [Equivalent of g_mass_storage with configfs](https://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-usb/msg90757.html) to write the following script which initializes the configuration for USB mass storage gadget through configfs and functionfs.

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e

CONFIGFS="/sys/kernel/config"
GADGET="$CONFIGFS/usb_gadget"
VID="0x0525"
PID="0xa4a2"
SERIAL="0123456789"
MANUF="Myself"
PRODUCT="MyProduct"

case "$1" in
    start)
        echo "Creating the USB gadget"
        echo "Loading composite module"
        modprobe libcomposite

        echo "Creating gadget directory g1"
        mkdir -p $GADGET/g1

        cd $GADGET/g1
        if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
            echo "Error creating usb gadget in configfs"
            exit 1;
        else
            echo "OK"
        fi

        echo "Creating Mass Storage interface"
        echo "\tCreating backing file"
        dd if=/dev/zero of=/home/pi/backingFile.img bs=1024 count=1024 > /dev/null 2>&1
        mkdosfs /home/pi/backingFile.img > /dev/null 2>&1
        echo "\tOK"

        echo "\tCreating gadget functionality"
        mkdir functions/mass_storage.0
        echo 1 > functions/mass_storage.0/stall
        echo "/home/pi/backingFile.img" > functions/mass_storage.0/lun.0/file
        echo 1 > functions/mass_storage.0/lun.0/removable
        echo 0 > functions/mass_storage.0/lun.0/cdrom
        mkdir configs/c.1
        mkdir configs/c.1/strings/0x409
        ln -s functions/mass_storage.0 configs/c.1
        echo "\tOK"
        echo "OK"

        echo "Setting Vendor and Product ID's"
        echo $VID > idVendor
        echo $PID > idProduct
        echo "OK"

        echo "Setting English strings"
        mkdir -p strings/0x409
        echo $SERIAL > strings/0x409/serialnumber
        echo $MANUF > strings/0x409/manufacturer
        echo $PRODUCT > strings/0x409/product
        echo "OK"

        echo "Binding USB Device Controller"
        echo `ls /sys/class/udc` > UDC
        echo "OK"
        ;;
    stop)
        echo "Stopping the USB gadget"

        cd $GADGET/g1

        if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
            echo "Error: no configfs gadget found" 
            exit 1;
        fi

        echo "Unbinding USB Device Controller"
        echo "" > UDC
        echo "OK"

        echo "Removing Mass Storage interface"
        rm -f configs/c.1/mass_storage.0
        rm -f /home/pi/backingFile.img
        rmdir functions/mass_storage.0
        echo "OK"

        echo "Clearing English strings"
        rmdir strings/0x409
        echo "OK"

        echo "Cleaning up configuration"
        rmdir configs/c.1/strings/0x409
        rmdir configs/c.1
        echo "OK"

        echo "Removing gadget directory"
        cd $GADGET
        rmdir g1
        cd /
        echo "OK"

        echo "Disable composite USB gadgets"
        modprobe -r libcomposite
        echo "OK"
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Usage : $0 {start|stop}"
esac
```

Everything seems to work until the "Binding USB Device Controller" step. After having configured everything, there is still nothing in `/sys/class/udc/`.

At boot, the folder `/sys/class/udc/` doesn't exist and it appear after I run the script with `sudo ./mass-storage-load start` but it stay empty.
The configfs partition is also mounted at boot.

After I ran the script, three new modules are loaded

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
usb_f_mass_storage     44899  2 
libcomposite           52156  10 usb_f_mass_storage
udc_core               40853  2 usb_f_mass_storage,libcomposite
```

However with nothing in `/sys/class/udc` I don't know which usb device controller I should bind to this gadget.
I searched a lot on the internet to find someone that could have a similar issue but I'm not able to find something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally the problem was that the module dwc2 had to be loaded.

So I added `dtoverlay=dwc2` to `/boot/config.txt` and `dwc2` at the end of `/etc/modules` to load it automatically at boot.

Comment: Which OS? `dwc2` gets loaded on Arch Linux without any change to `/etc/modules` or `/etc/modules.load.d`. Also, I think you have a typo with the module name. `modinfo dwc2` works, `modinfo dcw2` does not.

Comment: It was on raspbian but I don't remember which version, certainly on raspbian stretch lite as it's what I'm usually using on rpi zero. I fixed the typo mistake ;)